# Passing by Reference or Value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the difference between passing by value and passing by reference. When would passing by reference run faster than passing by value (and vice versa)? Also, in what cases would passing by reference use less memory than passing by value (and vice versa)?

Comment: Passing by reference more efficient, because your avoiding creating an temporary object in memory, thus no allocations or de-allocations of memory, your just passing address of your already created object.( but you have to remember, passing by reference, your modifying original variable, and again you can make `const` your argument to avoid modification inside the function). passing by value means your are creating temporary copy, thus compiler has to do more job hear, create temporary object and pass to function only to be destroyed at end of function.

Answer (score 3):

> When would passing by reference run faster than passing by value (and vice versa)?

This can be a tricky question, as it often comes down to "it depends".

Passing by reference avoids making a copy of the parameter. For simple objects, copying is not that expensive (maybe no more expensive than using a reference), but for large objects it could be. If you are using someone else's class, you might have to resort to performance testing to have an idea of the performance savings of avoiding the copy.

Passing by reference also adds a level of indirection whenever the value of the parameter is needed. This means that using the parameter is slower. The more often you use the parameter, the more pronounced this effect is. Again, measure to learn the size of the effect, but my understanding is that outside performance-critical parts of your code, an extra level of indirection is usually insignificant.

> Also, in what cases would passing by reference use less memory than passing by value (and vice versa)?

This is fairly straight-forward. When you pass by value, you place the value on the stack. The space required is the size of the object. When you pass by reference, you place a pointer on the stack. The space required is the size of a pointer. If `sizeof(argument) < sizeof(argument*)` then pass-by-value takes less memory, whereas pass-by-reference takes less memory when `sizeof(argument) > sizeof(argument*)`.

On a typical 64-bit system, passing by value uses less memory for most of the basic types (such as `char`, `short`, `int`, and `float`) and is a tie for most of the others (such as `long long` and `double`, but not for `long double`). Keep in mind that this is typical, not mandated by the standard.

---

As a rule of thumb, for `long` and smaller, pass by value unless you need a reference (because the function is supposed to change the supplied argument). For objects that maintain multiple pieces of data, pass by reference unless you need a copy. A class that is documented as "cheap to copy" should probably go in the former category (pass by value), regardless of your understanding of how much data it maintains.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass by reference, you're able to modify the passed variable. However, if you pass by value, you are not able to do this. Arrays are an exception to this rule, you can pass them however you want. Hope this helped!

Comment: Technically, you can't pass an array by value, only by reference. You can, however, pass the pointer it gladly decays to by value.

Comment: This answer does not address the question asked, the question regarding speed and memory.