# Which is more efficient in this scenario: return a member by reference, or return as pointer?

Tags: c++, performance, class, pointers, reference

As an example, I have a class that uses the Eigen library as follows:

```
class A
{ 
    private: 
    Eigen::MatrixXd _matrix; 
    public: 
    Eigen::MatrixXd GetMatrix() const; 
}
```

GetMatrix() as of right now is implemented as such:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A::GetMatrix() const 
{
   return _matrix; 
}
```

Let's say in main.cpp, I have a function that does the following:

```
void PrintMatrix(const Eigen::MatrixXd &matrix)
{
   std::cout<<"Print matrix: "<<matrix<<std::endl; 
}

int main()
{
     A obj; 
     PrintMatrix(obj.GetMatrix()); 
     return 0; 
}
```

In the GetMatrix() function, my goal is to return the _matrix value, and it will be used as seen in main(). I would like the most efficient approach.

I am new to optimization and just starting to warm up to pointers. As you guys can see, GetMatrix() currently returns a value, and I am aware that returning by reference and returning by pointer is much faster than by value, but what are the risks/pros and cons of doing either? And which of the two would be preferable for my case?

Comment: There won't be a difference in terms of performance efficiency. The point is what to do if you can't return a valid value.

Comment: Have you tried to measure and profile this yourself? For example by doing this a million times? Remembering to enable compiler optimizations for the test program?

Comment: In general: [When to use references vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058339/when-to-use-references-vs-pointers)

Comment: Thanks for the swift responses everyone. And @Someprogrammerdude at least for return by value, the actual code I'm working on that does something similar I've measured performance for but only like 10,000 times

Comment: I would point you specifically to [answer currently #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058376) in the question mentioned by user4581301.

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT. Are references and pointers faster than returning by value because it keeps from creating "copies" of the member variable everytime the getter function is called?

Comment: Modern compilers are good at [return-value optimizations and copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization). Return by value, and only if it turns out to not pass the requirements you have and that it's a major top-three bottleneck (measured and profiled on an optimized build) you need to bother with explicit and detailed micro-optimizations like that.

Comment: Sometimes your reasoning for being faster applies, sometimes not. You get into some of the same details as are covered by [Passing by Reference or Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455532).

Comment: Thanks all. This has been very insightful!

Answer (score -1):

In your case I would have a method with the signature:

```
const Eigen::MatrixXd& GetMatrix() const noexecpt;
```

The compiler will use the most suitable method available.
In your case because your print function takes a const reference as a parameter, the reference version will be used automatically.

Nowadays I use the keyword noexcept for public methods. This tells the client that exception handling is not needed. Sometimes the compiler can optimize for that.

Also for optimization prototyping I strongly recommend:
https://godbolt.org/
There you also have links to the tools Quick-bench and CppInsights.

And I just need to give you a const reference to a Youtube talk:
Jason Turner “Rich Code for Tiny Computers

Comment: What does adding the additional const do?

Comment: The problem with just *adding* this function is that its signature is exactly the same as the one already shown by the OP. Remember that return type is not part of a functions signature used for overloading.

Comment: The additional const acts as a promise:
"I the caller shall not modfify this value given to me by reference."
Thanks  Some programmer dude for the correction.

Comment: Regarding "shall not modfify this reference" it's a little misleading, as a reference itself can't be modified. It's the object *being referenced* that can't be modified.

Comment: *"The compiler will use the most suitable method available."* -- based upon the arguments provided, not based upon the return type.

Comment: I believe the question asked for a comparison between returning a reference and returning a pointer. How does returning a pointer fit into your answer?

Comment: *"In your case because your print function takes a const reference as a parameter, the reference version will be used automatically."* -- this is false. The compiler chooses an overload of `GetMatrix()` based upon its arguments, not on where the function is used.